# How to find $ (x, y) $ corresponding to $ z_\text{max} $ in $ \{x, y, z\} $-table?

Tags: list-manipulation, data, maximum

I have been given a table `a` of the form

```
a = {{"Bob", "6549", 3000},
     {"Alice", "7598", 80},
     {"Andrew", "9593", 120},
     {"Frank", "1013", 30000},
     ...
    };
```

Each row contains information about a donator namely his name (Bob, Alice, Andrew, etc.), his phone number (6549, 7598, etc.) and money he has offered to a foundation (\$3000, \$80, \$120, etc.) under concern.

So if `a` consists of say `10000` rows is there any simple way to find out who is the best donator with Mathematica?

P.S.   "best" donator $:=$ has donated the most money

Comment: `MaximalBy[a, Last]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides [`MaximalBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html) in the comment by @HenrikSchumacher, you can also use [`TakeLargestBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeLargestBy.html):

```
TakeLargestBy[a, Last, 1]
Most[%[[1]]]
```

---

Also, [`OrderingBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderingBy.html) can give you the position of the "best" donator in the original table `a`:

```
OrderingBy[a, Last, -1]
```

Comment: Ευχαριστώ, καλή συνέχεια

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
  {{"Bob", "6549", 3000}, {"Alice", "7598", 80}, 
   {"Andrew", "9593", 120}, {"Frank", "1013", 30000}};
```

**1.**

If we also want to know the index we can use `PositionLargest` (new
in 13.2)

```
p = Flatten @ PositionLargest[list[[All, -1]], 2]
```

{4, 1}

and use it inside `Part`

```
list[[p]]
```

{{"Frank", "1013", 30000}, {"Bob", "6549", 3000}}

**2.**

Create an `Association`

```
ds = GroupBy[list, Most -> Last, First];
```

and query it with `TakeLargest`

```
TakeLargest[2] @ ds
```

<|{"Frank", "1013"} -> 30000, {"Bob", "6549"} -> 3000|>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = {{"Bob", "6549", 3000}, {"Alice", "7598", 80}, {"Andrew", "9593", 
    120}, {"Frank", "1013", 30000}};
max = Max[Transpose[a][[3]]];
pos = Position[a, max][[1, 1]];
a[[Sequence @@ pos, 1 ;; 2]]
(*  {"Frank", "1013"}  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{"Bob", "6549", 3000}, {"Alice", "7598", 80}, 
        {"Andrew", "9593", 120}, {"Frank", "1013", 30000}};
```

---

Using `SortBy`:

```
SortBy[list, Last][[-1]]

Most[%]
```

*Results*:

> {"Frank", "1013", 30000}
>
> {"Frank", "1013"}